# Posting a dictionary data with an argument in httppost using DefaultHttpClient

Tags: android, http, post, entity

The server API in one of the parameter expects a dictionary value. For example check the phone parameter the following:

data={"name": "Dummy Name", "phone": **{"number": "123456", "type": "mobile"}**}

I am using DefaultHttpClient in my Android application and so far all the example shows how to post the basic name value pair with the httpPost request.

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "Hi"));
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

Is there a way to set entity with a dictionary?

Comment: (-1 unclear what you're asking ) ... if you wana post simple string you can use StringEntity ... but for me it looks like a JSON ...

Comment: OK that's what I was looking for. I will try using StringEntity.

Answer (score 0):

What it looks like is that you are going to have to create a class that is LIKE `BasicNaveValuePair`! Something like a `BasicNamePhonePair` class that will be addable to the List. StringEntity I don't believe will fix your problem. You kind of have to parse the JSON...not just store the JSON string.

You you have is... `data={"name": "Dummy Name", "phone": {"number": "123456", "type": "mobile"}}`

what the example shows is... `data={"id": "12345", "stringdata": "Hi"}`

Basically you have to create a way to add a data structure along with "name"...and add those two things to the List!

To kind of illustrate what you have to store...

```
public class Contact {
    string name;    // "Dummy Name"
    Phone phone;    
}

public class Phone {
    string number;    // "123456"
    string type;      // "mobile"
}
```